# Approximation of continuous functions in L1

Tags: measure-theory

Can it be said that polynomials with $0$ constant term approximate continuous functions in $[0,1]$ in the $L^1$ norm?

I have shown that polynomials with $0$ constant term uniformly approximate continuous functions $f$ such that $f(0)=0$ in $[0,1]$, but I'd like to move to arbitrary continuous functions in $[0,1]$, approximate them with the same polynomials, but make the norm less restrictive by using the $L^1$ norm.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough to show that continuous functions with $f(0)=0$ approximate arbitrary continuous functions. Let 
$$
g_n(t)=\begin{cases}nt,&\ 0\leq t<1/n,\\ 1,&\ t\geq1/n\end{cases}
$$
Now given $f\in C[0,1]$, let $f_n(t)=f(t)g_n(t)$. Then $f_n(0)=0$, $f_n$ is continuous, and 
$$
\|f-f_n\|_1=\int_0^1|f(t)-f(t)g_n(t)|\,dt=\int_0^1|f(t)|\,|1-g_n(t)|\,dt=\int_0^{1/n}|f(t)|\,(1-nt)\,dt\leq\frac{\|f\|_\infty}{n}.
$$

Comment: Last equality isn't true. Should be 1-nt in the integral, shouldn't it?

Comment: You are right. It is corrected now. Thanks.